# how to count the number of times a visualforce page opened by user?

Tags: salesforce, crm, visualforce, apex

I need to understand the process of how we can count the number of a specific visualforce page opened by a user. The reason for this question is to see if i can find out what are the pages mostly used by users and enhance it so that i can make users life easier :).

What i know is we need to use some kind of function when page is loading. If there is any otherway i would love to understand it. If you have questions please feel free to ask, i know sometimes we can't put something in writing what we have inour mind.

Comment: You should consider asking this question over in [salesforce.stackoverflow.com](salesforce.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

**Server-side**

VF page controllers (both the custom controllers and extensions) are not allowed to run any DML operations. The reasoning behind that is somewhat simple - the act of just navigating to given page and maybe reading some data shouldn't have side effects like DB updates. So if you're thinking about saving some data - you'd be doing it either in the actions invoked on these pages or in the `<apex:page ... action="{!doSomething}">`. But the `action` parameter is frowned upon because it's a nasty workaround for this (sane) limitation. If you plan to submit your code to SF security review or the Checkmarx code quality review - this will be pointed out.

**Client-side**

Install some tracking javascript either into sidebar or into the VF pages. (this JS could even  do RemoteAction or something like that as an alternative to this `action`).

You can also have a look at Google Analytics (depends if you're fine with aggregated top 10 visited pages or you need something per user).

As @jordan.baucke mentioned - try cross-posting on Salesforce.StackExchange.com :)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple with JavaScript, Global Variables, and object and some ajax calls(RemoteAction). The sample code would be:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"/>
<script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(document).ready(function(){
        var userID = '{!userInfo.getUserID}';    //Gets user ID

        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.ClassName.MethodName}',    //Method where you increment the click counter stored in the record for that object
                userID,
               //Function on completion
        );
    });
</script>
```

However, I suggest that its not wise to do any DML/SOQL on page load.